# Late 90s CGI show about soldiers fighting giant bugs

Tags: story-identification

I have memories of maybe 15-20 years ago as a young child watching a TV show that had something to do with soldiers/space marines fighting giant bugs. I recall it being CGI because I distinctly remember a scene of someone falling off a cliff and looking really stupid as they did so. It's possible that this person ended up not being dead after a while, but then they got visions about the bugs and what their goals/plans were.

The only other thing I can think of was that at some point in time, the main characters were walking around inside one of these big bugs (an especially big one) and it had organic mouthlike doors. Maybe they shot one at one point to make it open, but at this point I'm almost certain I'm getting this memory mixed up with something else.

I'd just like to know the name of this show so I can maybe watch it again, or at least put together these vague memories from my past. It's not something I've seen anything about for a long time, so I don't think it was very successful, and I don't have any names to go on.

Comment: [Starship Troopers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120201/) is the first thing that comes to mind

Comment: @calccrypto OP asked about a series not a movie.

Comment: @mg30rg *Starship Troopers* is actually an entire franchise. There is the original novel, a series of movies, games, and a spin-off show.

Comment: @Beofett I wasn't aware of any live action TV series.

Comment: @mg30rg Who said anything about a "live action" TV series?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It sounds a lot like the **Roughnecks: Starship Troopers Chronicles** (based on the movie mentioned in sabbahillel's answer), which was CGI. I don't recall any scenes inside a giant alien (although it would fit with the series), but I only ever saw assorted episodes on tv.

See:
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0190198/

Comment: The TV series had a *lot* more in common with the books.

Comment: Back in the day pretty much the only CG animated shows were Starship Troopers, Reboot and Beast Wars. Has to be it.

Comment: This looks like the most likely answer, once i get a chance ill watch a few episodes to confirm

Comment: As I recall Roughnecks did have a guy falling off of a cliff in one of the earlier episodes (I believe it was in the first arc set on Pluto). It also did have a giant ship/carrier bug, that I believe had a few episodes with marines inside of it (probably in the Homefront or Klendathu arcs). It also had the Carl character sense the bugs plans at least once, and possibly several times. As far as I know, it is not in print on DVD/Bluray anymore. I managed to snag a [full-series box set](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0009I8QI6) about 10 years ago that can still be found for around $40

Answer (score 14):

Was it perhaps *[Space: Above and Beyond](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112173/)?* That was a US series involving space marines fighting bug-eyed aliens, in a similar vein to *Starship Troopers*, which has been mentioned. But the OP said it was a TV series, which made me think of *Space: Above and Beyond*. It was (as I recall) a bit darker, more intelligent, and more adult than *Starship Troopers*, and I thought it had a lot of potential. Sadly it was cancelled after one series.

Comment: This is what popped into my mind immediately as well.

Comment: Agreed. It might worth mentioning that - while "Space: Above and Beyond?" was more intelligent and darker than the "Starship troopers"  movie, the same does not apply to the book the movie was based on which was a satirical story pointing out the dangers of pseudofascist dictatorships.

Comment: I've accidentally duplicated this answer. Sorry! I believe that it's the right one, the time frame is right, and interestingly it pre-empted Starship Troopers by a couple of years, albeit earnestly and without the tongue-in-cheek commentary about American cultural trends (especially when you consider the direction things might take now... ).

Comment: Unless the series I remember isn't the one you're describing, it wasn't CG, which suggests it's unlikely to be the one the OP was looking for.

Comment: S:A&B was live-action with CG elements, which is how I read the original question (people 'looking stupid' falling off a CG cliff). Agree with @mg30rg about the book of *Starship Troopers*; it took a totally different tone to the film.

Answer (score 8):

Big bugs, organic door, CGI. Sounds like [Lexx](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0178149/).

> The main characters of the series are the Lexx and its crew. The crew consists of the captain of the Lexx, Stanley H. Tweedle, the love slave Zev/Xev, the undead former assassin Kai, last of the Brunnen-G, and the love-crazed robot head 790. Together they are looking for a new home. The background conflict of the series is the war between Mankind and the Insect Civilization, in which each side seeks the annihilation of the other. It was foretold to Kai that one day he will destroy the last remnant of the Insect Civilization.

This is Lexx:
[image]

Comment: Does Lexx have space marines, and do they fight other individuals from Lexx's species?

Comment: Lexx, while a great series, was not very suitable for children, young or otherwise. Also, while the outside, space screens were CGI, the interior scenes had real actors.

Comment: @Jonah There are no space marines. Closest to soldier is Kai, undead assassin. And no, there is no Lexx species, it's just one organic ship.

Comment: @GAThrawn Maybe not suitable for children, but I have seen it when I was around 11 years old, and I liked it.

Comment: I had totally forgotten about this show. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: This was one of the weirdest series I've seen. Cool in a campy way.

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like [Starship Troopers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_Troopers_%28film%29) which was from the [novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_Troopers) by Robert Heinlein. The movie is from 1997.

> Starship Troopers is a 1997 American satirical military science
>   fiction action film directed by Paul Verhoeven and written by Edward
>   Neumeier, originally from an unrelated script called Bug Hunt at
>   Outpost Nine,[3] but eventually licensing the name Starship Troopers
>   from a science fiction novel by Robert A. Heinlein. It is the only
>   theatrically released film in the Starship Troopers franchise. The
>   film had a budget estimated around $105 million and grossed over $121
>   million worldwide.
>
> The story follows a young soldier named Johnny Rico and his exploits
>   in the Mobile Infantry, a futuristic military unit. Rico's military
>   career progresses from recruit to NCO and finally to officer against
>   the backdrop of an interstellar war between mankind and an insectoid
>   species known as "Arachnids".

The movie is very loosely based upon the Robert Heinlein  novel of the same name. Note that the actual plot does not really follow the novel and much of the script was changed to fit the way Hollywood wanted to portray it (such as including "action" and "sex" scenes).

> Starship Troopers is a military science fiction novel by American
>   writer Robert A. Heinlein, published hardcover in December 1959. The
>   story was first published (in abridged form) as a two-part serial in
>   The Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction as Starship Soldier.

Comment: The bugs are CGI, and have aged well.

Answer (score 3):

The timeframe sounds about right for '[Space: Above and Beyond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space:_Above_and_Beyond)', a series that had a lot in common with 'Starship Troopers' (it pre-empted it, in fact). I thought it was reasonably good for what it was, an earnest 'space war' series with some exploration of the issues presented.

It didn't last long.

Edit: I didn't see the answer by @benshepherd, somehow. My apologies.

Comment: "Reasonable good" - they lost me in the pilot when they where *manually* synchronizing their clocks.

Comment: Ha ha, well, it was far from perfect. I can suggest that perhaps they had mechanical clocks for one reason or another (synchronising clocks manually is still a thing when not on a mobile phone network).